# Calculating Standard deviation of percentages?

Tags: standard-deviation

I have the following data

X 1 2 3 4 5…

Y 10 12 13 14 15…

X/Y 10% 16% 23% etc.

How do I find the standard deviation of percentage (last line)? Can I treat the ratio as a normal distribution and apply regular SD formula?

Comment: This looks like a standard textbook problem. Please review the [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) of the `self-study` tag and add it if at all applicable.

Answer (score 2):

You should clarify your question to be clear whether you want the sample standard deviation of the collection of percentages or the estimated standard deviation of *each* percentage.

I'll discuss the second case. You should also clarify the question enough that I can remove some of the 'if's below.

*If* the Y's are total counts of objects of which the X's are counts of some particular subset (such as X='number of people with red hair in a classroom', and Y='number of people in the classroom'), *and* if you can assume independence of occurrence of the characteristic being counted in X *and* if you can assume constant probability of occurrence of that characteristic, ...
then conditional on Y, you're in a binomial sampling situation and the estimated s.d. of the fraction X/Y is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{Y} \frac{X}{Y}(1-\frac{X}{Y})}$, which you can convert to percentage terms by multiplying by 100%.

Answer (score -1):

The *classical* definition of the standard deviation estimate is independent from the theoretical distribution of the data, so you can perfectly apply it to a set of percentages $$ s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left( z_i - \overline z\right)^2 } .$$

Depending on the distribution, you can have other estimates, though, with different properties.

Comment: You should divide by $N$ of $N-1$ within the square root

Comment: @Luis Mendo means $n$ **or** $n - 1$. (I'm matching the $n$ notation.)

Comment: Indeed! Correction made.

Comment: It is incorrect that the standard deviation is independent of the distribution of the data. These data are binomial proportions. The binomial distribution has only a single parameter, $p$ which is used to calculate both the mean and the variance. The standard deviation is simple the square root of the variance. There are several other distributions where the mean and standard deviation are related by the same set of parameters.

Comment: My answer, as was the question, was about the *estimate*, not the distribution parameter. I modified my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @DaltonHance : I don't understand why you mention the binomial distribution...

Comment: You state that "the general definition of the standard deviation [estimate] is independent from the theoretical distribution of the data". This is incorrect. It is important to separate the concept of the parameter from the estimator, which you conflate. There may be many estimators of the standard deviation and one may be better than another based on the distribution. The general definition of the standard deviation (not estimate of standard deviation) is $\sigma = \sqrt{E[X^2] - E[X]^2} $, which does depend on the distribution of the data. Hence the binomial example.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot I mention the binomial distribution because OPs is asking about how to find the standard deviation of a sample of integer ratios. This is naturally described by the binomial distribution. For the binomial distribution, there are better estimators of the standard deviation of the population.

Comment: I get your point, and I still don't see how it makes my answer incorrect: my point was that you the definition of the "standard deviation as everyone knows it and which is an estimate" can be applied to any sample. Yes, of course the standard deviation as a parameter depends on the distribution of the sample. However, if you want to provide other estimators better suited to this problem, why not propose your own answer?